# Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to post something on http://indianrailforums.in using selenium script. I am able to login and reach this page: http://indiarailinfo.com/blog using the selenium script, but after I click post button I am not able to send text in the text area.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://indiarailinfo.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("e")
element.send_keys("yagyank@gmail.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("p")
element.send_keys("suvrit")
element.submit()
driver.get("http://indiarailinfo.com/blog")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Post')
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/textarea")
#element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME + "abc");
#element = driver.find_element_by_name("TrainBlog")
element.send_keys("suvrit")
#driver.quit()
```

EDIT: Issue solved by using submit button and using driver.implicitly_wait(10) just before calling xpath

Comment: When you say you are "not able to send text" - what actually happens? What errors or behaviour do you see?

Comment: Nothing happens after the post option is clicked a text area comes and then it all stops

Comment: whereas what I want is I want to write in that text area which comes after clicking post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you **have not submitted the form**. Either call `submit()`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/textarea")
element.send_keys("suvrit")
element.submit()  # it would find the parent form and submit it
```

Or, click the `post` button:

```
post = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.postbtn')
post.click()
```

Comment: NO luck still the same. And yes I am getting an error which is this http://pastebin.com/ngM2fwfZ

Comment: Done by adding the submit as well as driver.implicitly_wait(10) just before x path.Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

I was able to post with PhantomJS driver. It should work with Firefox either.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get("http://indiarailinfo.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("e")
element.send_keys("yagyank@gmail.com")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("p")
element.send_keys("suvrit")
element.submit()
driver.get("http://indiarailinfo.com/blog")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Post')
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/textarea")
print element.tag_name
#element.sendKeys(Keys.HOME + "abc");
#element = driver.find_element_by_name("TrainBlog")
element.send_keys("chuh-pook")
element.submit()
#driver.quit()
```